# keyPressed method java

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

```
public class Board extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener{
 public static final int HEIGHT = 950;
 public static final int WIDTH = 1000;
private JFrame jf;
 private Enemy enemy;
 private boolean board[][];
 public Board( int r, int col) {
        this.rows = r;
        this.columns = col;
        enemy = new Enemy(rows, columns, this, extraEnemy);

        board = new boolean[rows + extraEnemy][columns + extraEnemy];

        setSize(WIDTH , HEIGHT);
        jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setSize(WIDTH , HEIGHT);

        (new Thread(this)).start();

        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        jf.setLocation((d.width - 950) / 2, (d.height - 1000) / 2);

        jf.add(this);
        jf.addKeyListener(this);
        jf.getContentPane().add(this);
        jf.getContentPane().add(player);
        jf.setLayout(null);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        }
          @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            long d = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (d + 100 > System.currentTimeMillis());
            this.repaint();
        }
    }
@Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println(" hereeee");
        if(e.getKeyCode() == VK_SPACE){
  //          bullet = new Bullet(player.getX(), player.getY());
    //        bulletVec.addElement(bullet);
      //      clickedOn =true;
        }
    }
```

I'm writing a program in Java Swing in which I have a `JPanel` and inside, I define a `JFrame` that helps me add `keyListener` to my panel. But although I write `addKeyListener` method, the program doesn't enter the `keyPressed` method.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`. 3) Common problems with using `KeyListener` result from a) the component is not focusable b) the component does not have focus. 5) *"thanks a lot for your help"* It would help us to help you if you *asked a question.*

Comment: thank you for the suggestions but I you know I have been coding since 4 months ago and our professor wants a project in which using keyListener is an obligation.. can you at least help me deal with the "having focus" problem?

Comment: *"can you at least help me deal with the "having focus" problem?"* Did you read comment (3)? What have you tried based on your understanding of that comment? See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) Note further that if you can be helped, you need to do something based on that comment (research, try things) and get back to us with a more specific question. SO is not a place to come for a tutor, you need to be able to help yourself based on tips that are offered. So far, I see no sign of that.

Comment: I solved the bug by adding this.setFocusable(true);
        this.requestFocusInWindow();                                                                 to my code.. and why are you angry all the time :/ are you a literature teacher whose job is to specify what is a "question" and what is not?!!!:/  thank you anyways :)

Comment: *"why are you angry all the time"* You have not yet seen me angry. Heck, I did not bother voting to close your question for 'unclear what you are asking' or down vote it for 'not showing research effort'. And I didn't swear once! I suggest you grow a thicker skin. Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: This is a well known issue with `KeyListener` and you should be using the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead which fixes the issue